# Encryption of downloaded media file from iPhone app

Tags: ios, security, encryption, download, media

I am developing an iPhone app which contains sensitive media(video) files downloaded through a website. I need to make sure the data is securely encrypted and no one access it. I intend to use existing encryption mechanism. I have tried searching good application/articles but most of them talk about encrypting images which is not 100 % secure. I also looked into Crypo APIs. Please can someone guide me what is the best API to use. If their is any good example it will be good help.

Comment: What do you mean "existing encryption mechanism"? Your video files are already delivered encrypted?

Comment: What does this mean: "most of them talk about encrypting images which is not 100 % secure"? What is insure? OTOH, I am not aware of anything that lis 100% secure.

Comment: @Marcus, by "existing encryption mechanism" I mean to say existing APIs for encryption, or any other method which is being developed for encrypting media files. Videos do not come with any encryption. They are just like a media file with .avi extension.

Comment: @Zaph I have seen an example for encryption here:http://www.gamedevhelper.com/protecting-your-assets-ios-only/ which is good example to encrypt images inside iPhone app. In my app the media files downloaded through app are very sensitive and needs to be protected from being copied or distributed by the user.

Comment: I think most likely you just want HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

The encryption is easy, use CommonCrypto and AES. The hard part is handling the keys. By "handling the keys" I mean securely creating and providing them to the users, handling their lifetimes.

If there is any real value in the media files consider hiring someone with substantial experience in the field. Mistakes that totally makes the security useless are very easy.

See [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) by Rob Napier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zaph, I will look into this project. And special thanks for understanding my question, I should perhaps explain my query with more details.